# Facebook Android app link opens Facebook page instead of Play Store

Tags: java, android, facebook, applinks

I generated and using a facebook App Link to my Android app.

When the app is installed on the device, it correctly runs the app.

When the app isn't installed, the link brings to my app's **Facebook page**, instead of opening its **Google Play page**. This is not what I want.

Any idea?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: There is a lot of code involved, but I followed everything in standard way. By the way, removing the app page link from facebook solved the problem.

Comment: I didn't like working with Facebook API. Facebook's documentation and development standards are much weaker than Google's and Microsoft's. Just compare a Google documentation with a Facebook one. The latter is inaccurate, sometimes misleading, forgets important details etc.

Comment: Yeah I agree, Facebook can be a pain to work with compared to some other apis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem disappeared after I removed the reference to my app's facebook Page (inside "Contact Info" in the app's facebook dashboard).